# How to use the timestamp from the systemd-journal with promtail / loki instead of the generated one?

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail, systemd-journald

I use *promtail* to scrape my systemd journal and sent it to a Grafana Loki server. My problem is, that on busy systems the timestamp is quiet a bit off (between the timestamp shown in the journal on the host and the timestamp shown in Grafan/Loki).

> The *timestamp* stage is an action stage that can change the timestamp of a log line before it is sent to Loki. **When a timestamp stage is not present, the timestamp of a log line defaults to the time when the log entry is scraped.**—[Loki Docs](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/timestamp/#timestamp)

For file based logs parsed with *static config* (e.g. nginx logs) I solved this  by parsing the timestamp from the log entry and set it via the *timestamp* stage. But I have no idea, how to get the timestamp from the `journal` scraper.

Looking at the [man page for journal fields](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html) I tried to use `SYSLOG_TIMESTAMP` and `_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP` as sources for the timestamp, but they seem not available to *promtail* (I'm stuck on *CentOS 7* with *systemd 219*).

Comment: Here's a link to my [promtail config](https://gist.github.com/brutus/7c8164a85579ae61fdf84c452c2827aa).